Ask git to show all files ever changed by a user
I am on a feature branch. I would like to see files that I have modified in past merge requests. Pulling from a Stack Overflow answer, I enter the following command:
git log --stat --committer=$(whoami)

This does indeed give me a list of commits that include changes by me, but the list unfortunately comprises just one commit -- on my current feature branch, from a day ago -- even though I have made many other changes in this repository over previous months. So my question is twofold:

Am I correct in assuming that the command above only shows changes on the current branch?

Assuming so, is there a way to show all commits I've ever made in this repository, including those that correspond to the merging of past merge requests in GitLab?


(I realize that commits within a merge request will have been squashed and are now unavailable, but I'm hoping I can still at least see the big commit that corresponds with each merge of a feature.)
====
EDIT: Thanks to Lasse's excellent suggestion in the comments, I have verified that git config user.name and whoami show the same string.

The command should show all commits from your branch head and backwards through history. However, are you sure whoami returns the right value for this search? What does it show? Does it show the same username that you've used on all your commits? On my Macbook, it shows lassevk, but my email starts with lasse@, so your statement finds nothing at all. Maybe you have various usernames in play across all your commits?

Thanks, Lasse. I have verified that git config user.name and whoami return the same string. That was definitely worth checking. I'll add it to the question.

Go back through your log with no filtering, to find an actual commit you expected your statement to include, and take a look at the metadata for that commit. To get a fuller look at the metadata, you can do git cat-file -p COMMIT_HASH.

Yes, sure enough, GitLab seems to be committing some changes as Firstname Lastname instead of the condensed form used in CLI commits. Which is interesting, since the GitLab profile shows the condensed form. In any case, thanks again.

I am not familiar with GitLab, but I know that GitHub will show my GitHub username, and not the name or address I have used when committing. This is because it knows that the commits were made by me. Maybe there is an issue with how you've configured GitLab, if, for instance, you complete merges and pull requests on GitLab instead of locally.

Additionally, when GitHub completes merges on the website, it registers itself as the committer, but specifies that I am the author. This shows my name on the commit, even though GitHub made it. Your search statement would fail to find these commits. Additionally, if you ask GitLab to squash your branch into a single commit, there is no commit left from that change with your "committer" name on it. The only commit left is the squashed one, made by GitLab.

Try this instead: git log --stat --author=$(whoami)
